# authentication via telnet on android emulator fail

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb, telnet

I am trying to authenticate on Android emulator to pass some geoPoints to track location.

I followed all tutorials, so first I did:

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

It connects and says ok, then after that I open my file where the token of the android is stored, and do:

```
auth <mytoken>
```

No solution is working so far, I don't why if I am following every step:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try without <>

auth yourtoken